# How to display array object php to ajax js?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, function

I have a function that return array object from php using mysql and i want call array from ajax function using javascript, but i don't know how display array object php in javascript dinamic table or console log....

my php file:

```
$age = $_POST["param"];  //value ajax param
$list = BussinesLayer::getUsers($age);  //load my list

//list properties ej:  list->getName(), getAge(), getOcupation()->getDescription(), etc..

echo json_encode($list);
```

my js function:

```
 fnListUsers: function() {

    var agedata = $("#txtAge").val();

    $.ajax({
        type        : "POST",
        url         : "../ControllerFile/SearchUsers.php",
        data        : {"param" : agedata},
        dataType    : 'json',
        success     : global.fnSuccessList,
        error       : function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            alert("Request: " + XMLHttpRequest.toString() + "\n\nStatus: " + textStatus + "\n\nError: " + errorThrown);
                      }
    });

},
fnSuccessList: function(data) {
    var array = JSON.parse(data); // -> dont work  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    var array2 = jQuery.parseJSON(data);  // dont work  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

    //how display my arrayobject ?
    console.log(data.getName, data.getOcupation.getDescripition);

}
```

Comment: did you console.log(data) before using JSON.parse on it to see if you have any data in it?

Comment: im try with:  console.log(data) and console show

Comment: im try with:  console.log(data) and console show 

"Object {0: Object, 1: Object, 2: Object"

Comment: why are you parsing when it's already parsed  `dataType    : 'json',` this already done the job for you

Answer (score 1):

Your success function already has the `data` in json format. So you don't need to parse it again in JSON. just use `console.log(data)` to see your object.

```
fnSuccessList: function(data) {
    var array = JSON.parse(data); // remove this
    var array2 = jQuery.parseJSON(data);  // remove this

    console.log(data);

}
```

Comment: you must check his code, he is making mistake in his code.

Comment: @AjayDeepakKumar When did I say that he isn't making a mistake?? And your answer is exactly the same what I've said!!!

Comment: Oh my bad i did not see your answer. my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are doing wrong you used `dataType    : 'json'` that already parsed data but after that you are again try to parse. that is causing error.

```
fnListUsers: function() {

    var agedata = $("#txtAge").val();

    $.ajax({
        type        : "POST",
        url         : "../ControllerFile/SearchUsers.php",
        data        : {"param" : agedata},
        dataType    : 'JSON',
        success     : global.fnSuccessList,
        error       : function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            alert("Request: " + XMLHttpRequest.toString() + "\n\nStatus: " + textStatus + "\n\nError: " + errorThrown);
                      }
    });

},
fnSuccessList: function(data) {

    // this will show your data
    console.log(data); 

    /* Don't use this just access data directly 
     var array = JSON.parse(data); // -> dont work  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    var array2 = jQuery.parseJSON(data);  // dont work  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
   */


}
```

see in console if your data looks like this then it's parsed 
[image: Parsed Image]

if looks like this then it's not parsed [image]

Comment: try to see console.log(data) and see does that property is defined or not.

Comment: for example, the property getName() is undefined, but console log show this: 

Object
0
:
Object
__proto__
:
Object
1
:
Object
__proto__
:
Object
2
:
Object
__proto__
:
Object
__proto__
:
Object

Comment: {"0":{},"1":{},"2":{}}  

is strange, becouse i test list in php file and list have values :/

http://imgur.com/a/N3RsA

Comment: that does not make any sense you are trying to access value which is not even exist